# bind function to ajax loaded data on() not working jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this function that works well in my page. the problem is that It doesnt work in results loaded by Ajax.

**HTML**

```
  <ul id="container">

    <img src='icons/px.gif' data-src="images.png\" class='lazy-img' />
    <img src='icons/px.gif' data-src="images.png\" class='lazy-img' />
    <img src='icons/px.gif' data-src="images.png\" class='lazy-img' />
    <img src='icons/px.gif' data-src="images.png\" class='lazy-img' />
    <img src='icons/px.gif' data-src="images.png\" class='lazy-img' />
    <img src='icons/px.gif' data-src="images.png\" class='lazy-img' />


         </ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 setTimeout( function(){
     $('.lazy-img').each(function() {this.src = $(this).data('src'); 
          }).removeAttr('data-src');
                  }, 800);
```

How should I bind this function with the container?

Comment: Are you saying you also have an ajax call that is dynamically loading your `<img>` tags (and you want to call that function after the elements have been loaded)?

Comment: yes. I want to bind this `settime` function to those elements

Comment: You would have to do that in the `success` callback of your ajax function (after you have added the elements to the DOM)

Comment: If you are expecting elements added due to an ajax call to have handlers you will have to add the handlers after the new elements are added to the page. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: can I delegate this function...using on() or something like that? or maybe convert thi settime to a proper function and then delegate it?

Comment: @joe Check my answer, it should work. Let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul#container').on('select',function(){
setTimeout( function(){
     $('ul#container .lazy-img').each(function() {
     this.src = $(this).data('src'); 
          }).removeAttr('data-src');
                  }, 800);
});
$('ul#container').trigger('select');

});
```

What you can do is bind an event with the `ul#container` and on document ready trigger that event.

In  your AJAX success just trigger that event again!!

```
$.ajax({
  . 
  .
  success: function(data){
   $('ul#container').trigger('select');
  },
});
```

Also put this AJAX function in `document.ready`
You can trigger this event wherever you need to call that function.

Try this, hope it will help.

Comment: Its just a custom event. You can use anything. For example use joe.

Comment: Now when you trigger event joe like this $("ul#container").trigger("joe"); you can bind that event by $("ul#container").on("joe",function(){...});

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in my code. I have update the function to bind the event please check now.

Comment: Also if it answer your question please approve the answer. Thanks @joe

Comment: Yeah it helped a lot. thank you. this question...why using `trigger` instead of `on("trigger".` what would be the line using this last one.

Comment: You need to find the event using on function so we need to add on("trigger". Also can you please mark the answer as approved? Thanks @joe